# How to download the record of firms included in the SP100 index?

Tags: market-data, data, sp500

I need to download a dataset that describes the constituents of the SP100 index over time. I have an account on WRDS and hence I can get the constituents of the SP500 fairly easily, but it seems that they don't have the same interface for the SP100.

Is the community aware of any resource that will allow me to download the series of officially included firms? Thanks!